# Getting error related to NiceVibrations plugin after using Facebook Unity SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

Our game uses the [NiceVibrations plugin](https://nice-vibrations-docs.moremountains.com) for haptic feedback, and the [Facebook Unity SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/) for user login.

After updating the Facebook Unity SDK to version to 13.2.0, we are suddenly getting a Parse Error in Xcode.

It marks these 3 lines inside the `UnityFramework-Swift.h` file with an "Expected a type" error:

```
+ (void)RegisterHapticEngineFinishedCallbackWithCallback:(HapticCallback _Nonnull)callback;
+ (void)RegisterHapticEngineResetCallbackWithCallback:(HapticCallback _Nonnull)callback;
+ (void)RegisterHapticEngineErrorCallbackWithCallback:(HapticCallback _Nonnull)callback;
```

The `UnityFramework-Swift.h` file is used by the `FBUnitySDKDelegate.h` file, which is then used by `FBUnityInterface.mm` file.

Our other games that still use version 11.0 of the Facebook Unity SDK don't get that error. I've also looked at the "UnityFramework-Swift.h" file for those games and didn't see those lines. In fact, there are no lines related to NiceVibrations in the entire "UnityFramework-Swift.h" file.

Has anybody come across this issue before?

Answer (score 1):

Just got the same problem integrating the latest Facebook SDK into my game with haptics.
I've found that POSSIBLE reason for that is the cyclic dependencies coming from the

```
#import <UnityFramework/UnityFramework-Swift.h>
```

It is used both in FBUnitySDKDelegate.h and MMNViOSCoreHapticsInterface.mm
I've found a way to build the game, but it is stupid, and I am not an IOS guru to find a better way.

- I've built the game.
- Removed the import manually from the Facebook file.
- Commented out everything that was using this import(Everything related to Facebook tournaments, which I do not use anyways)
- Done.

This allowed me to build a game and it runs successfully, but I am eager to know how to fix this properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you downgrade the Facebook SDK version the problem will be solved, this problem is caused by Facebook SDK.

I used version FBSDK 9.2.0 and it worked without any problems.

you can download archived Facebook SDK from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/downloads/)